# How to Edit Local Group Policy using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

In Local Group Policy Editor (GUI) there is a setting called `Do not allow window animations` located in `Computer Configuration`->`Administrative Templates`->`Windows Components`->`Desktop Window Manager` that I would like to set as Enabled using the powershell, Since my windows version is professional I can added the RSAT GroupPolicy capability to my machine which I did and now I can use the [Group Policy Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/ee461027(v=technet.10))

but I am clue less on how to Enable that feature using the commands

I tired to use

```
Get-GPO -Name "Do not allow window animations"
```

but this returns

```
Get-GPO : Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest.
```

the grouppolicy module is wokring fine but I can't figure out how to query or change the value of any settings in the GPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cmdlets in order to change values you can use the PolicyFileEditor module from the gallery
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/3.0.1

Comment: To understand the relation between gpedit.msc, registry and registry.pol this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1192458/428228) is a must-read!

Answer (score 1):

The Get-GPO function is meant exclusively for Domain Group Policies, and not Local Policies, which it seems you are referencing. The description for the module also mentions this:

> Gets one GPO or all the GPOs in a domain.

In order to modify local policies, you need to make a change to the respective setting in the registry

For example to disable the Shutdown button, you would need to modify:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideShutDown
Value = 1
```

Comment: This seems to be true for some settings but not all. E.g. if I change the registry settings for AccountLockout > ResetTime (mins) or AccountLockout > MaxDenials, those values are not reflected in group policy even after a reboot.

Comment: Same can be set for the Windows Update policies. These are still configured in MMC even after you delete the related registry keys/values.

Comment: See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1192458/428228) to understand